# One time password question

Tags: cryptography, one-time-password

Suppose `F(X) = (5X) mod 9` is used to generate a one time password.

I am supposed to generate the first 8 values using the above formula, starting with the seed value of `F(5)`

Well I know that `F(5) = ( 5 * 5) mod 9` gives me 7. Thats my first value. But what about the rest of them?

I know what the answers will be, but I'm not sure on how to use the formula to get these values?

Answer: 5,7,8,4,2,1,5,7

Answer (score 4):

For the rest use formula:

```
f(x)=(5*x) mod 9
```

For example if you have f(5)=7 the next step is

```
f(x)=(5*7) mod 9 = 35 mod 9 = 8
```

and so on